# Выделяемая память в Си

Tags: c

Есть программа, которая переводит число в двоичное представление в виде строки. Нужно, чтобы не было начальных нулей, которые не используется. Преподаватель сказал, что нужно использовать что то с *log* числа, которое переводим по основанию 2, и округлить его в большую сторону (так можно узнать количество выделяемой памяти конкретно под нужные цифры без нулей в начале).

Если можете, объясните, пожалуйста! Просто интересно что он имел в виду

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX sizeof(c) * 8 + 1

void ltoab(long num, char s[]){
    int i;
    s[MAX] = '\0';
    for(i = MAX - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        s[i] = (num & 1) + '0';
        num >>= 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", s);
}

int main(void){
    long c;
    int b, a;
    int mas[100];
    char *s = (char*)malloc(33 * sizeof(char*));
    printf("Skolko chisel ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for(b = 0; b < a; b++){
        scanf("%d", &c);
        mas[b] = c;
    }

    for(b = 0; b < a; b++)
        ltoab(mas[b], s);
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно думать в сторону того, что есть логарифм.

Comment: Двоичный логарифм числа - это степень в которую надо возвести 2 что бы получить число. Для двоичной системы счисления двоичный логарифм и есть количество необходимых разрядов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если до понимания логарифмов ещё далеко, то можно пойти обратным путём. Числа от двух до трёх представляется двумя цифрами: 2 = 10(2), 3 = 11(2). От четырёх до семи тремя: 4 = 100(2), 7 = 111(2). С восьмёркой прибавляется ещё один разряд. Здесь закономерность - при достижении новой степени основания системы счисления у числа появляется новый разряд. Отсюда получается, что можно находить количество разрядов узнавая "пройденную" степень основания.

Здесь как раз пригождается логарифм. Его следует понимать как функцию, для которой верно следующее утверждение: *log_x_(y) = z* => *x^z = y*. То есть, логарифм от восьми по двум равен трём - в эту степень нужно возвести двойку для получения восьми:

*log_2_(8) = 3* => *2^3 = 8*

На практике можно обойтись такой функцией, которая возвращает количество цифр числа в двоичном представлении:

```
int binDigitNumber(int x) {
    int k = 1;
    while (x > 0) {
        x /= 2;
        k++;
    }
    return k;
}
```

По сути, это целочисленный логарифм по основанию 2 с единицей.

**UPD.**

Сейчас выделяется память одна на все числа:

```
char *s=(char*)malloc(33*sizeof(char*));
```

Если же это действие перенести в тело метода (что вообще правильнее), то выделять память на строку можно будет под конкретную длину числа; также это избавит от *страшного* использования локальной переменной в define:

```
void ltoab (long num){
    // количество символов = количество цифр + символ конца строки
    int symbols = binDigitNumber(num) + 1;
    char *s = (char*)malloc(symbols * sizeof(char*));
    s[symbol - 1] = '\0';
    for(int i = 0; i < symbols - 1; i++){
        s[i] = (num & 1) + '0';
        num = num >> 1;
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

Comment: я понимаю что такое логарифм,но я не могу понять как можно связать это с выделением памяти под числа, определённого размера

Comment: @Евгений 0k, сейчас будет и это.

Comment: Во-первых, отсутствует free. Во-вторых, **C99** поддерживает variable-length array, поэтому можно заменить `malloc` на простое объявление вида `char s[symbols]`. В-третьих, логичнее не инкрементировать переменную symbols, а работать с ней как с количеством цифр.